# switching between cameras in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have 2 camera in my 2D scene. i want to change the player camera to another one.
but it gives me error

here is the error:

```
MissingComponentException: There is no 'Camera' attached to the "player" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
```

You probably need to add a Camera to the game object "player". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
SwitchCamera.Start () (at Assets/scripts/SwitchCamera.cs:10)

this is my code:

```
public Camera camera1;
public Camera camera2;




void Start () {

    //camera2 = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();

    camera1 = transform.FindChild("player").gameObject.camera;



}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C)) {

        camera1.GetComponent<Camera> ().enabled = true;
        //camera2.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;

    }
    }
```

Comment: Please remove commented out code. It only makes it confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as for current Unity3D version:

> Property camera has been deprecated. Use GetComponent() instead. (UnityUpgradable)

as stated in API [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-camera.html).

Also, if you need to switch between cameras, one way would be to assign them from inspector and then go for `enabled` property.
Other way round is finding it in scene (quite inefficent if you don't know exact location of it). I would recommend creating some sort of service or camera manager that would be a single point of changing cameras. Remember that cameras work for all your scene, not for certain object only (but they can use culling to render only exact layers you want).

**Example:**

```
public Camera camera1;
public Camera camera2;

public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        //Swap enabled state to opposite one provided that only is on at a time
        camera1.enabled = !camera1.enabled;
        camera2.enabled = !camera2.enabled;
    }
}
```

`camera1` and `camera2` should be assigned from inspector, that is drag and drop `GameObject` with `Camera` component attached to the field of script inspector (first camera to *camera1* field and second camera to *camera2* field and so on).

Comment: the camera change but not to the another camera . when i try to change it says no camera and giving me the same error again

Comment: Are you using the code I've provided? There is no way for it to throw error you are referring, as you are not using `camera` readonly property anymore in it.

Comment: yes . exactly and only your code . i should explain something.

Comment: my main camera is following the character then another camera in the scene is targeting a puzzle . i want to click on some object and show the puzzle . but here we go errors

Comment: im using unity 3d 5 version . is it make diffrence?

Comment: MissingComponentException: There is no 'Camera' attached to the "player" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Camera to the game object "player". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
SwitchCamera.Start () (at Assets/scripts/SwitchCamera.cs:10)

Comment: hey error is gone but no camera when i try to change

Comment: It's not an error in my code then. I'm not using `camera` property of *"player"* anywhere.

Comment: It probably means that both were set to `.enabled = true` on beginning and script disabled them both on `KeyDown`.

Comment: yep i think it was a unity bug . now about the no camera ??

Comment: Check if both cameras were not enabled on start. My script reverts current state of both cameras, so if both were enabled on start, both will get disabled and *vice versa*.

Comment: here is the final cod if(FcamOn==false){
    FcamOn=true;
    camera1.enabled = true;
    camera2.enabled = false;
   }
   else{
    FcamOn=false;
    camera1.enabled = false;
    camera2.enabled = true;
   }

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question I don't see function **FindChild** in documentation of Transform.
I think you should use **Find** function:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html
You can use this simple code to try find problem.

```
void Start () {
    GameObject go = transform.Find("player").gameObject;
    if (go == null){
        print("GameObject not found");
    }else{
        Camera camera1 = go.GetComponent<Camera>();
        if (camera1 == null){
            print("Camera not found");
        }
    }
}
```

If you will get "Camera not found" maybe you didn't add Camera component to GameObject "player" or Camera Component is destroyed by other Script or Camera component don't exist yet, because you add camera after run this script. I dont't know all scripts and hierarchy of gameobjects and components in project.

Comment: Zak this is the error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
DreemClick.Start () (at Assets/scripts/DreemClick.cs:18)

Comment: Actually, there is `UnityEngine.Transform.FindChild()` in UnityEngine assembly. It's just not documented anymore as it's deprecated in *Unity3D 5.3* as it's duplicated functionality of `Transform.Find()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that message means you need to drag and drop your Camera into the inspector.

The next issue you're going to have is the

```
public Camera cam1;
```

is referencing a camera component, not a Camera Objects. So when you try:

```
cam1.enabled = false;
```

You're leaving the audio-listener component on, and turning off the camera component (which will throw another warning message).

**The solution:**

```
public GameObject cam1;

cam1.SetActive(false);
```

which will "disable" the Camera Object (all the components, including the audio-listener components and camera components)